# request using HTTP Outh 2 authentication with PHP curl not work?

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I have set up a http request using `PHP CURL` with following code.

```
      <?php

$para='{
  "payment_method": "bacs",
  "payment_method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
  "set_paid": true,
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "product_id": 13,
      "quantity": 2
    }

  ]

}';

       $process= curl_init('http://xxx');
        $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
                curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
                curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxfa18148227334d91&
                   oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
                   oauth_signature=xxxxx%253D&
                   oauth_timestamp=xxxx&
                   oauth_nonce=xxXbG&
                   oauth_version=2.0"));
                curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $para);
                $return = curl_exec($process);
                print_r($return);
                curl_close($process);
        ?>
```

It's given following error i want to get woocommerce order api using curl this is woocommerce rest api related i have also add this `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` in .htaccess but still is not work.

```
  {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Someone please help me how do i resolve this ?

Comment: Where is the `$process` variable coming from? As the error says, it is `null`. Please post your full code.

Comment: The error is clear - The `$process` which you pass as the first parameter to a call to curl_setopt() is null. Nothing at all to do with OAuth as you mentioned in the title. In your code `$process` is the result of a call to `curl_init()`...now go and read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php . It says "Returns a cURL handle on success, FALSE on errors.". So really it should return _something_. How it comes to be null is a mystery, based on your code. However you might at least double-check your code to see whether the call to curl_init() succeeded or not.